# How to group by property of child entity and get sum of child entity in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to group data by child entity and get sum of child entity. So, I tried this linq:

```
context.Parent.Include(p => p.Child).GroupBy(p => p.Child.Type).Select(g => g.Sum(p => p.Child.Amount));
```

Above linq results in an error. However, if I were to get sum of parent entity it will work.

```
context.Parent.Include(p => p.Child).GroupBy(p => p.Child.Type).Select(g => g.Sum(p => p.Amount));
```

Why cannot I get the sum of child entity?

Comment: What is the error? What version of EF Core: 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x?

Answer (score 1):

It is limitation. After GroupBy you cannot use navigation properties. Also after GroupBy all Includes are completely ignored, so omit them.

You query can be written in the following way:

```cs
var query = 
    from p in context.Parent
    group p.Child by p.Child.Type into g
    select new 
    {
        Type = g.Key,
        Sum = g.Sum(c => c.Amount)
    };
```

Lambda syntax variant:

```cs
var query = context.Parent
    .GroupBy(p => p.Child.Type, p => p.Child)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
       Type = g.Key, 
       Sum = g.Sum(c => c.Amount)
    });
```

Comment: I am not being able to implement above linq in lambda. Can you provide lambda function implementation?

Comment: Install ReSharper an do it in single click. It will be ugly and unmaintainable. Learn LINQ Query.

Comment: @ranjeep, added Lambda syntax variant.

Comment: What if I need to group by the property of Parent entity, and get sum of property of child entity? As you have mentioned that after group by navigation properties cannot bed used, how can it be achieved?

Comment: After GroupBy i mean in projection. Groping key can be navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in your model you have a sequence of `Parents`. Every `Parent` has a property `Child`. Every `Child` has two properties: `Amount` and `Type`.

You forgot to tell us your specification, and gave us some code that does not do what you want. So it is a bit difficult for us to know what you want.

I think that you want to make groups of `Parents` that have the same value for `Parent.Child.Type`. From every Parent in the group you want to take the value of `Parent.Child.Amount` and sum theses values.

You are right, for this you should use one of the overloads of Enumerable.GroupBy. My advice would be to use the overload that has a parameter resultSelector:

```
// make groups of Parents with same value of Parents.Child.Type:
var result = dbContext.Parents.GroupBy(parent => parent.Child.Type,

// parameter resultSelector: for every Type, and all Parents that have this Child.Type
// make one new:
(type, parentsWithThisChildType) => new
{
    // do you want to know the type?
    ChildType = type,

    // from all parents in this group, select the Parent.Child.Amount and Sum them:
    TotalChildAmounts = parentsWithThisChildType
        .Select(parent => parent.Child.Amount)
        .Sum(),
})
```

In words: from your sequence of Parents make groups of Parents that have the same value for Parent.Child.Type. From every group make one object as follows:

- Is desired, take the common Type of all Parent.Child.Type in this group
- from every Parent in the group, select the value of Parent.Child.Amount.
- Sum all values of this Amound, and put the result in TotalChildAmounts